# Having trouble format a string into a date object

Tags: java, parsing, date, formatting

I have a string that looks like this

```
Aug 16, 2013,11:30:10
```

The comma can be replaced by a different separator and the date & time position can be switched.

I am trying to use this format for my SimpleDateFormat(dtString is the String above):

```
Date d = null;
     try {
         d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy,hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dtString);
      } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MonKaiClientImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } 
      return d;
```

but when I run d.getYear() the result is ***113***.

All of the other Date methods return the correct result except .getYear(). Am I missing something? Is my SimpleDateFormatter wrong?

Comment: The date format should be MM only not MMMM d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy,hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dtString);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use [`Date#getYear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29). It's deprecated.

As for the result you get, it's as specified in the Javadoc:

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

Use Calendar API instead. Or even better, if you can use 3rd party library, then I would really suggest you to try [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net). Or wait for *Java 8* to come next year, that has a new Date Time API.

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha. Thanks! I have to actually use the Date object in this case because it will be going into a MongoDB [field](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/) and they don't handle Calendar objects yet.

Comment: @Sempus. Oh! You can convert `Date` to `Calendar`, and back easily. Go through their API, you would see appropriate constructor for both of them.

Comment: Sounds good. So I guess I'll just store the date in Mongo and when I get it out I'll convert it to a Calendar object and use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to check the result of SimpleDateFormat parsing is this

```
System.out.println(d);
```

and it shows correct result

```
Fri Aug 16 11:30:10 EEST 2013
```

the problems is that Date methods interpreting year, month, day, hour, minute, and second are deprecated. See Date API